# Why does SVMLite misclassify with few training inputs?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, svm, svmlight

I am using SVM Light to classify images that are processed with OpenCV. Images are made to B/W, blurred a little, and the HOG detector from opencv is used to create a feature vector with vectors from positive images labeled with a 1 and negative images with a -1. When I run the SVMLight train file on 7 positive and 7 negative process images, it misclassifies 4 of the 7 negative files.

However, at larger inputs, it trains without misclassifications. Does anyone know why this may be the case?

[Correctly classifying negative images with a larger training input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1qkl.png)

[Misclassifying 4 of 7 negative images while training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ5sW.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the disadvantages of SVMs in general. For instance in the scikit-learn [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html), it's mentioned:

> The disadvantages of support vector machines include:
>
> - If the number of features is much greater than the number of samples, the method is likely to give poor performances.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you have any understanding *why* this is the case?